# Alternate class name in controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

I just realized that alternate class names for controllers in ExtJS 4.2.1 don't work the way I expected them to:

```
Ext.define('AppName.controller.subnamespace.Controller1', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    alternateClassName: 'AppName.Ctrl1',
    // ...
});
```

Accessing the controller with the getController method of the app (or any controller) works for both names (the long one & the alternate one) but returns 2 distinct instances of the controller:

```
var ctrlInstance1 = AppName.app.getController('AppName.controller.subnamespace.Controller1'),
    ctrlInstance2 = AppName.app.getController('AppName.Ctrl1');

console.log(ctrlInstance1 === ctrlInstance2); // --> false
```

Is this intended behavior or a bug? If its a bug I'm going to file a bug report...

**Thanks**

*Ps.:* I've also asked this question in the official sencha forums but didn't get no response so far: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?271970-Alternate-class-name-in-controller

Answer (score 0):

This is a sure way to write confusing code. Alternate class names feature was invented to provide backwards compatibility with previous Ext versions, where class names were different for certain components. It should not be used in the application code, unless you want to make your application harder to maintain.

Comment: I fully understand what you are saying and still think that there are certain situations where those alternate class names are a great tool if used carefully and consistent and can really enhance readability of code in a way that justifies the negative impact it has in terms of maintainability.

Comment: Can you give me a use case? So far I can't see how this feature can be useful for Controllers.

Comment: I can't in the comments section here because it takes a little more than 550 characters, but actually I've already posted one at the Sencha forum: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?271970-Alternate-class-name-in-controller&p=997150&viewfull=1#post997150